# Error when I tried to concatenate two strings

Tags: c++

I have two strings and I want to concatinate them,so, I used this code
 `char* a = "Hel";
  char* b = "lo";
  strcat(a,b);` but when I run my application It show this error `Access violating writing location`

Comment: I'm sorry.  Did you try googling the error or reading the doc for strcat?

Comment: 1. Both these strings should be declared as const, as they are pointers to literals
2. String a is too small to fit the concatenation of both.
3. You should use std::string.

Comment: You're lucky it didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're both (`a` and `b`) string literals -- you can't write to them. In fact, you shouldn't be using `char *a = "Hel";` at all -- you should use `char const *a  = "Hel";`, in which case the code won't even compile.

Try something like this instead:

```
std::string a = "Hel";
std::string b = "lo";

std::string c = a + b;
```

`strcat` in C++ (even when used correctly) is highly suspect at best.

Answer (score 2):

`a` is pointing to a literal that can not be modified and on top of that `strcat` needs space in the destination to append the `src` string to. As mentioned by Jerry you can just use `std::string` which makes things much simpler. If you need to use `char *` then you could so something like this:

```
char str[20] ;

strcat( str, "Hel" ) ;
strcat( str, "lo" ) ;
```

Although, none of the old `C` style string methods are really great to use, unless you are doing it just to learn. If you are going to be using them a lot you should read at least a few articles on [Secure Coding in C and C++: C-Style Strings](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/library/abstracts/news-at-sei/feature120061.cfm).

Answer (score 1):

Just extending what Jerry Coffin said.

The non-`std::string` solution would be something like:

```
char str[10];
strcpy(str,"Hel");
strcat(str,"lo");
```

But `std::string` is generally better.

Answer (score 1):

The first declaration makes "a" a pointer variable pointing to four bytes of memory, with the characters 'H', 'e', 'l', and byte 0. The strcat writes the 'l' into the fourth place, over the zero byte, then the 'o' into the place after the fourth byte. That place in the memory is not yours to write to, so you get an error. Instead, make sure there is enough space at the destination to hold the concatenated string. If possible, don't use strcat by itself, but something safer, like strncat.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to one of these resources.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/

You should use the reference pages on cplusplus.com as much as possible.

Also the man pages:  `man strcat` from Unix command line if you are in a Unix system, although they can be found online.